# Not able to use actions in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-redux, babeljs

I am trying to implement Redux state management in my react native app but I am facing an issue . I did the same thing in my react app and it worked fine . I am using typescript template .

```
export * as actionCreators from "./action-creators";
```

**Error**

```
TransformError src/state/index.ts: Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to this problem is :

```
import * as actionCreators from './actions/loginAction'
export {actionCreators}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have used export instead of import, Replace export with import and then check

Comment: Please be more specific or add code example.